# How to use shared preferences in android for google authentication?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am a beginner in android development and I want to create a login page for my application. I am using **Firebase** as my backend server. Using Authentication services provided by Firebase I am able to create user successfully but as we know, user must input login credentials at the time of application installation.

So, any one suggest me how to develop this part in android where it takes credentials on app installation and store them locally so that user need not enter credentials all the time he launched application.

Thank you in advance guys!

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36544061/storing-google-login-details-using-shared-preference-in-android-studio

Comment: you cannot store google credentials in shared preferences , you can only store if user logged in by google succesfully or not

Comment: To avoid getting downvote, You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions should be avoided.